# Python paramiko type "yes" after user name " and then password

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, paramiko

I know my question may have posted  in stack overflow somewhere  but i cant find the answer.

I am trying to automate SSH login into a server  . When i enter username ,  a prompt is send by server " Do you accept and acknowledge the statement above ? (yes/no) :" and i have to type "yes" and then password .
[image]

I am not able to figure out how to send yes and then password  in Python .  Below is my code.:

```
import paramiko
ip_address = "1.1.1.1"
username = "abc"
password = "1234" 
# Define the list of show commands to execute
show_commands = ["show interfaces", "show routing table", "show system info"]
# Create an SSH client object
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
# Automatically add the Palo Alto firewall's SSH key to the local key store
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
# Connect to the Palo Alto firewall using SSH
ssh.connect(hostname=ip_address, username=username, password=password)
# Execute each show command and print its output
for command in show_commands:
     stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
     output = stdout.read().decode()
print(f"Output of '{command})':")
print(output)
print("-" * 50)
# Close the SSH connection
ssh.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to automate the process of sending "yes" to the prompt and then the password, you may try to use the paramiko library along with the expect method provided by the pexpect library. `pip install pexpect`. As for your code, you may try following change.

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_session = pexpect.spawn(f"ssh {username}@{ip_address}")

# Wait for the prompt and send 'yes'
ssh_session.expect("Do you accept and acknowledge the statement above ? (yes/no) :")
ssh_session.sendline("yes")

# Wait for the password prompt and send the password
ssh_session.expect("password:")
ssh_session.sendline(password)

# Wait for the shell prompt
ssh_session.expect("#")

# Execute each show command and print its output
for command in show_commands:
    ssh_session.sendline(command)
    ssh_session.expect("#")
    output = ssh_session.before.decode()
    print(output)
ssh_session.sendline("exit")
ssh_session.close()
```

Comment: . Yes this is what i was looking for . I was not aware of pexpect . Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: : i am getting below  error . I ahve installed python on windows .. PLease help me on the same  ...                                                                                                                                         ssh_session = pexpect.spawn(f"ssh {username}@{ip_address}")
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'pexpect' has no attribute 'spawn'